# nodejs paypal ipn keeps invalid

Tags: node.js, express, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I know this has been discussed several times - although researched every single thread I am not able to get it running. Before giving up on this I want to give it a last try:

My environment is up-to-date nodejs with express and bodyparser. I developed my app and tried to implement a simple Paypal Express checkout. I used the paypal-ipn but was not able to get a VALID response from Paypal. I played around with what I believed to be the problem (implemented a raw body parser just for the paypal callback, played with encoding and header options, switched settings in the paypal account from windows to utf8 encoding) but you might already know, nothing worked. So I decided to leave my app and go from scratch with a plain and simple new setup. I used a different approach found on the net and again ended up with the same error. I then decided to go "live" as sometimes it is reported, that the sandbox always returns invalid. That try cost me 50cent transaction fee...and stayed invalid :-)

What somehow confuses me is that most of the discussions I found are several years old. As I used 2 different pieces of code (which both were and still are) reported as valid I think it's  fair to assume it's not a general mistake in programming logic. There might have been a change on the Paypal API or updated nodejs packages broke something. So please if any of you guys can point me in the right direction....

Here's my current code. I left some bodyparser alternatives in it just to throw it into the discussion. And again, I don't want to to adorn myself with borrowed plumes. Most of the code are snippets from the net:

```
var express = require('express');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');
var colors = require('colors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;


colors.setTheme({
    silly: 'rainbow',
    input: 'grey',
    verbose: 'cyan',
    prompt: 'grey',
    info: 'green',
    data: 'grey',
    help: 'cyan',
    warn: 'yellow',
    debug: 'blue',
    error: 'red'
});

var app = express();
var bpJSON = bodyParser.json();
var bpUrl = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
});

var parseRaw = function (req, res, next) {
    req.body = '';
    var helper = '';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        req.body += decoder.write(chunk);
        console.log(req.body);
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        next();
    });
};

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (!~req.url.indexOf('/notipal')) bpJSON(req, res, next)
    else return next();
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (!~req.url.indexOf('/notipal')) bpUrl(req, res, next)
    else return next();
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (~req.url.indexOf('/notipal')) parseRaw(req, res, next)
    else return next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.end('Response will be available on console, nothing to look here!');
});

app.post('/notipal', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Received POST /'.bold);
    console.log(req.body);
    logger.log(req.body);
    console.log('\n\n');

    // STEP 1: read POST data
    req.body = req.body || {};
    res.send('200');
    res.end();

    // read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
    var postreq = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    for (var key in req.body) {
        if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var value = querystring.escape(req.body[key]);
            postreq = postreq + "&" + key + "=" + value;
            console.log('key: ' + key + ' value: ' + value);
        }
    }

    // Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
    console.log('Posting back to paypal'.bold);
    console.log(postreq);
    console.log('\n\n');
    var options = {
        url: 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Connection': 'close'
        },
        body: postreq,
        strictSSL: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        requestCert: true,
        agent: false
    };

    request(options, function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

            // inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

            if (body.substring(0, 8) === 'VERIFIED') {
                // The IPN is verified, process it
                console.log('Verified IPN!'.green);
                console.log('\n\n');

                // assign posted variables to local variables
                var item_name = req.body['item_name'];
                var item_number = req.body['item_number'];
                var payment_status = req.body['payment_status'];
                var payment_amount = req.body['mc_gross'];
                var payment_currency = req.body['mc_currency'];
                var txn_id = req.body['txn_id'];
                var receiver_email = req.body['receiver_email'];
                var payer_email = req.body['payer_email'];

                //Lets check a variable
                console.log("Checking variable".bold);
                console.log("payment_status:", payment_status)
                console.log('\n\n');

                // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
                // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
                console.log('Printing all key-value pairs...'.bold)
                for (var key in req.body) {
                    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        var value = req.body[key];
                        console.log(key + "=" + value);
                    }
                }

            } else if (body.substring(0, 7) === 'INVALID') {
                // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
                console.log('Invalid IPN!'.error);
                console.log('\n\n');
                console.log(body);
            }
        }
    });

});

var port = 80;
app.listen(port);
var msg = 'Listening at http://localhost:' + port;
console.log(msg.green.bold);
```

Console log shows two identical bodies for received and sent.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit a day later:
Things getting more curious. For further investigating I setup a wamp environment using Paypals own php example published on Github. What should I say: invalid. This drives me crazy...

Comment: I'm currently having the exact same problem. Couldn't get the answer below to work either. Did you happen to solve this in the end?

Answer (score 1):

This is my code. I had some random INVALID answers, those were also driving me crazy. The thing is, we have an interface in Spanish and sometimes the call from PAYPAL included special characters, but those were already escaped... we were escaping them again. So we removed the "querystring.escape" when composing the post request to paypal; that solved our problem.

This is the code:

```
function processNotify(req, res) {

    console.log('Receiving call in /paypal/notify as POST. Dumping req.body...');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));

    // STEP 1: Read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
    var postreq = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    for (var key in req.body) {
        if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // postreq = postreq + "&" + key + "=" + querystring.escape(req.body[key]);
            postreq = postreq + "&" + key + "=" + req.body[key];
        }
    }

    // Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
    console.log('Posting back to paypal');

    config.paypal.verifyOptions.body = postreq;
    request(config.paypal.verifyOptions, function callback(error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.log('Error: Response status code !== 200, it is:' + response.statusCode());
            return;
        }

        if (body.substring(0, 8) === 'VERIFIED') {
```

Comment: So the only Issue was parameter with special characters coming from paypal callback. Thanks Man!